# Can I have a full width (100%) footer and a header with 80%? (CSS, HTML5)

Tags: css, html

I am working on a responsive website.

Check it out [here](http://dt3berkay.comeze.com/deeltoets3/artikelen.html).

#### CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Helvetica;
    color: #333;
    background-image: url(../../img/back.png);
    width: 80%; /* zorgt dat er bij de linkerkant en rechterkant beide 10% weg gaat */
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    float: left; /* hierdoor blijft de footer onderaan */
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border-top: 2px solid #00BFFF;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

So I want to have the footer to be full width and the header to stay at `80%`.
But this is impossible since I've set the body of the website to `width: 80%`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: set back the body to 100%, and add a wrapper around your content with 80%, and place your footer outside of your wrapper.

Comment: That just makes a mess of my page, i have no idea how to clean it up so i used the method Nicael provided :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `width:125%; margin-left:-12.5%` to your footer.

---

A fast check: go to your website and run this javascript in the address bar to check it:

```
javascript:var footer=document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];footer.style.width="125%";footer.style.marginLeft="-12,5%";
```

Comment: +1. To me negative margins feel a little hacky but in truth they are valid and well supported.

Comment: It works, but it is not responsive. When i make the website smaller (mobile view) the edges of the text (in footer) are cut off..

Comment: Negative widths? Thats waay too hacky.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in media queries to make the text fit in the footer without the edges being cut off??

Comment: If you use negative widths then proportions will go out of control. A down vote for telling you not to use this method?? Think about this. Your desktop is 1000px for example. 125% of this would be 1250px. This might work perfectly fine for what you need here. However take this down to mobile. when the orientation is different and the pixels count alot more. Use the method described by **Moob**

Comment: All i had to do was add `    footer { width:100%; margin: 0 auto; }`. Works great now, thanks Nicael.

Comment: @JustSteveKing negative width? where did you see negative width?

Answer (score 1):

Section your page into three parts (header, main content section, and footer) and size each one as required.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Helvetica;
    color: #333;
    background:#eee url(../../img/back.png);
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
}

section, header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
}


footer {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    border-top: 2px solid #00BFFF;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section>The main content</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: This is the best bet, you don't want to use negative widths as one user mentioned - this will screw up when you resize your browser. Instead go for something along the lines of what **Moob** posted as this *is* the correct way to do it. If you need an element in your page to be 100% width why constrain your body element to 80%?? ALWAYS make your body 100% and then work inwards on your elements, this way as you shrink the screen everything will remain as expected instead of erratic behavior. 125% on desktop is **VERY** different to what it would be on a mobile

Comment: When i do this, my whole website looks messed up because of the sidebars (aside)...

Comment: Then you need to fix your sidebars, or your complete layout. Check that, 5 people suggest you the way i mentioned. Body 100%, wrapper 80%, (or header / content 80%) footer 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `margin:0px auto` and `width:80%` for header. Apply the CSS like below.

```
body {
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Helvetica;
color: #333;
background-image: url(../../img/back.png);
width: 100%; /* zorgt dat er bij de linkerkant en rechterkant beide 10% weg gaat */
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 400;
}

 header {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 6px;
margin-top: 0.5em;
padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest applying the 80% width to a .container div, and have that container act almost at the 'body' of the website. You can then place the footer outside of the container, but then wrap the footer content in the same .container div. I'm assuming you just want the background of the footer to be full width and the content to stay at 80%.

So for example (inline css to show the example):

```
<style>
.container{width: 80%;}
</style>

<body style="width: 100%;">

<div class="container">

    <header></header>

    <p>Rest of content</p>

</div>

<footer style="width: 100%;>

    <div class="container">
        <p>Footer content goes here</p>
    </div>

</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your body,content (a div that contains all your body html), header and footer the respectively those width values:

**Body:**

```
width:100%;
```

**Header:**

```
width:80%;
```

**Content:**

```
width:80%;
```

**Footer:**

```
width:100%;



<body>    
 <header>header</header>
 <div id="content">Your body content</div>
 <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

That should do it.